# Contact to contacts

Tags: custom-object, contact, relationships, related-list

I'd like to be able to relate a contact to multiple contacts. For example, John is a student, and I want him linked with Teacher A and Teacher B, etc.
I created a custom object "Teachers" and included in it a lookup to Contact. When I am on John's record, I can create a new teacher record from the Teacher Related List, but the only record it would pick or display is John's record itself. Whereas I am trying to display Teacher A and Teacher B in the related list. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of Creating a lookup of teacher Object on Contact create a Junction Object
2. Having Master Detail Relationships between Contact(Student) and Teacher
3. So next time you can associate a contact(student) with multiple teachers using this junction object by simply creating a record in the junction object
4. Add the related list of Junction Object on the contacts page layout with this you can come to know which teacher currently teaches the present Contact(Student)